# Input text (mysql table column for html table header)

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have this code from one of the question here in Stack Overflow...

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <?php
      $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            foreach ($row as $col => $value) {
                echo "<th>";
                echo $col;
                echo "</th>";
            }
      ?>
      <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
  // Write rows
  mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        ?>
    <tr>
      <?php         
    foreach($row as $key => $value){
        echo "<td>";
        echo $value;
        echo "</td>";
    }
    ?>
      <td><button id="edit_project_button(<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>)" class="edit-project-button edit button" onclick="editproject(<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>)">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have a mysql table named quiz1912 and the columns inside it are

id,name,quiz1,quiz2...

The user can add quiz so the column in my mysql table will add a column named quiz3 and it will continue as long as the user wants to add a quiz...

The above code will generate an html table like this:

```
id    name    quiz1    quiz2   Edit

1     john    (null)   (null)  (edit button)
```

I want to have a table like this...

```
id    name    quiz1    quiz2 

1     john    (input)  (input)
```

.... My question is.. is there any way so I can put an input text in one, two or more columns in a row so i can get rid of the edit project button... the columns that I should put a input starts with 'quiz' and the users can add quiz if they want so the quiz that will be added will have a name like quiz1, quiz2, ...

Comment: You didn't do a very basic thing, which is called separation of presentation from business logic. In this case you should pass a prepared array into a template, don't build that array in presentation

Answer (score 0):

okay after connecting to the database... first you could do something like declaring you variables for the column names you need like :

```
`$quiz = "quiz";  //these are the column names in your mySQL table that you will pass the value to $quiz 

$quiz1 = "quiz1";`
```

then you can declare a statement with an if clause that will query your mySQL database and select all the data you want to insert into the various columns of your table :

```
`if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT quiz FROM tablename WHERE condition")){

$stmt->execute(); 
$result = $stmt->get_result();`
```

Here's how you can declare a table for multiple values:

```
`echo  "<table border='1'> //format border for table
  <tr bgcolor='#ff00ff'> //color purple 
  <th> quiz</th> //these are the two columns that will show up in your table 
  <th> quiz1 </th>
 </tr> ";   //this signals end of columns for table


//now fetch result from your queried database

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['quiz']  . "</td>"; these statements will add values to table
echo "<td>" . $row['quiz1'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

$stmt->close(); 
}
echo"</table>";
}
$con->close(); `
```

I do not know if this will help exactly but I had to create a multi- column table where I had to select many attributes of an employee from a company database when their last name was entered into a search field, yours is different obviously I attempted to generalize the syntax I used for mine.

Comment: ahmmm...i think i didnt explain well my situation anyway i appreciate your answer sir. thank you. i just edit my question